# Ошибка java.lang.NumberFormatException при конвертации в Double

Tags: java, double

При конвертации этой строки `130,8000` с помощью `Double.parseDouble` возникла эта ошибка. Что нужно исправить?

**Код**

```
double temp = (Double.parseDouble(ud.getText().toString()) * Double.parseDouble(prv.getText().toString()));
```

**Ошибка**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "130,8000"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
at myTable.comapre10(myTable.java:650)
at myTable$1.actionPerformed(myTable.java:156)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Заменить запятую на точку пробовали?

Comment: Нет, не пробовал. Спасибо, работает!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Java дробные числа пишутся через точку. Если у Вас используется запятая, то Вам нужно либо заменить ее на точку

```
String str = "130,8000".replace(',', '.');
double temp = Double.parseDouble(str);
```

либо парсить с учетом конкретной локали

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
Number number = format.parse("130,8000");
double d = number.doubleValue();
```

Comment: В Java дробные числа хранятся в своем внутреннем формате, и при отображении, в наиболее распространенных западных форматах (EN-US и т.д.) в качестве разделителя плавающей части используется точка. Это к "В Java дробные числа пишутся через точку", что не совсем корректно. Ответ на вопрос корректный.

Answer (score 2):

Полагаю, что проблема в запятой. Необходимо использовать соответствующее форматирование:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
Number number = format.parse(prv.getText().toString());
double d = number.doubleValue();
```